# joomla site not run exactly in root server

Tags: joomla

when i run joomla in localhost, it works fine...

But when i run it in the root server it output the bellow result::

404 Not Found

The server can not find the requested page:

```
http://173.236.31.34/~interair/interaircon/www.interaircon.com/index.html (port 80)
```

But if i give the link with index.php

then output correctly:: Say -> http://173.236.31.34/~interair/interaircon/index.php

i want a solution about this problem. It's new kind of problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your $live_site value in your configuration.php file?